# Splitting and Moving selected jList value to jTable rows (SWING)

Tags: java, swing, jtable, substring, jlist

Hi I'm trying to make a program that will move a selected value from a list to a table. I can add the whole list value to one row, but what I wanna do is split the list value into a set of strings and set them to different rows in the table.

The list values will look like this:

```
123 Test St LA 1823 Yes
456 Test Dr NY 12345 No
```

The list gets values from text fields(Address,State,Zip,For Sale) and set all of it into just one line of string separated by spaces.

In the table I have 4 Rows:

```
|Address|State|Zip| For Sale|
|------ +-----+---+---------|
|       |     |   |         |
```

So in order to do this I have to split the string value from the list by space, but since the address text field includes spaces (i.e. 123 Test St) unlike other text fields, I have to figure out a way to split the string from the list so that I can set the Address, State, Zip, and For Sale value.

Here's my code snippet:

```
 private void addListActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    home.setAddress(address.getText());
    home.setState(state.getText());
    home.setZip(zip.getText()); 
    home.setSale(forSale.getText());

    String concat = home.getAddress() + " " +
                    home.getState() + " " +
                    home.getZip() + " " +
                    home.getSale();


    addVal(concat);

        address.setText("");    
        state.setText("");
        zip.setText("");
        forSale.setText("");

}    

private void addVal(String str) {
    jList1.setModel(dm);
    dm.addElement(str);
}

    private void addToTableActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    String s = jList1.getSelectedValue();
    //Split and set values and add to table
}
```

I could use:`String[] spaces = s.split(" ")`, but then I would need to handle the Address value since it includes multiple spaces as well, is there an easier way of doing this? Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Fill your JList with Home objects, not a concatenated String
- Use a custom list cell renderer to display a concatenated String derived from the Home objects in the list.
- Then when an item in the JList is selected, you've got a full Home object, not a String, and creating your JTable row should be trivial.